# Display Mysql Result in an alert dialog box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i would like to query mysql database for some result using PHP and display the result in an alert dialog box using javascript.
I can connect and query the database ontop on displaying the result in a php page but failed to display them in an alert window any assistance is highly appreciated.

```
$sql = "select * from $table where cmscode ='$theWholeCode' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo $row[2];
}
```

aftee getting the value 
    $row[2];

i want to display it in the alert box

Comment: Please attach your code. We can't "guess" what's wrong.

Comment: what have you tried? Show us some example code that shows you've at least tried something

Comment: Umm. Sorry, our crystal balls are all in the shop for repairs, so we can't magically read your mind and guess what your code looks like.

Comment: `<script>alert("<?php echo addslashes($result); ?>");</script>` though i would suggest console.log instead of alert

Comment: I would suggest researching AJAX and approaching it from that direction

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this on your page:

```
$sql = "select * from $table where cmscode ='$theWholeCode' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   echo 'alert(\'' + $row[2] + '\');';

   // or, as @3n1gm4 suggested (which I also recommend)
   echo 'console.log(\'' + $row[2] + '\');';

}

echo '</script>';
```

Comment: thanks guys for the help, just for information, whats the difference between console.log() and alert()

Comment: @RuyongaDan alert() will pop up a message on your screen so if you have a 100 records in your database, 100 pop ups will appear in your browser, 1 by 1.  Can be quite annoying.  Console.log will appear when you click F12 in Google chrome and navigate to the Console panel.  This is much better to use.  Don't use console.log in IE because your code will only work if you console is open; otherwise "console" will not be defined and it will break your code.